# Using logrotate to manage logs generated by PHP

Tags: php, logrotate

My PHP scripts generate log files and I am trying to use logrotate to manage them.

File `/etc/logrotate.d/php-logs`:

```
/srv/cache/*.log {
  daily
  notifempty
  size 800K
  rotate 5
  missingok
  compress
  delaycompress
}
```

This is working, except for the part that sometimes the log rotation process coincides with PHP trying to append the log.

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some log rotate options that might help. 
See copytruncate in http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html
This will create a copy and truncate the original file. Therefore, the log file doesn't have to be closed and it's held open by your php script.  Some log statements might get dropped between the copy and truncate operation.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, my solution (bandage) is done within PHP, but I realise that it may not be the most proper or elegant one.

```
<?php
function log_record($str, $file_name) {
    $n = 0;
    while ($n < 10) {
        if (is_readable($file_name)) {
            file_put_contents($file_name, str_pad($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], 15, ' ', STR_PAD_RIGHT).' ['.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").'] '. $str . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
            exit;
        }
        usleep(10000); // That's 10 ms, up to 10 times.
    }
}
```